# 4 variables in 2d plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently have a xy graph color being my third variable. Is it possible to make a 4th variable be represented by shape or size?
I've been trying to use shape to represent my 4th variable, but I am starting to doubt whether it's possible.
In the code below, is it possible to make the 'marker' parameter reflect the value of the 'Species' variable?

```
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(data=iris, x='petal_length', 
y='petal_width', c='sepal_length', cmap='coolwarm')
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you formatted your code. Others have done it for you but it's still hanging out in a queue. You, however, could make that happen instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But before we start, I'm not clear if you're mixing things or not. I'll explain it both ways.

Option 1, with `iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')` you're calling seaborn, which you've presumably already imported. Seaborn is built on top of matplotlib, so it's quite possible that what you really wanted was to do this in seaborn because it looks nice. If that's the case, you'd need a different set of commands and relplot would be a good option.

`sns.relplot(data=iris, x='petal_length', y='petal_width', size='petal_length', hue="species")`

Which would display this:

[image]

Option 2 is along the lines of using seaborn just for a quick set of data to plot but really wanting to stick with matplotlib for some reason.

For that, you need to set what indicates what the sizes are initially. You can then change those size in the paramaters.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
s = iris['petal_length']
sc = ax.scatter(data=iris, s=s*10, x='petal_length', y='petal_width',
                c='sepal_length', cmap='coolwarm')
```

Which would display this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have the 4th variable be reflected by the shape (assuming the var is categorical)?
I am struggling a little bit with how commands that apply to option 2 interact with seaborn. That being said, I didn't mean to call sns in the import step in the example. 

Thanks for the response!

Comment: Just a couple of quick comments/questions: 1) What (specifically) is the 4th variable you would want? There are a total of 5 dimensions in the dataset. Normally, it's one feature per dimension of data. Redundancy is fine if makes things more clear but it often doesn't. Either way, you need to have an idea in mind to *test*. 2) Seaborn for just the data is legit -- I don't think matplotlib comes with any dummy data but you have to import it (obviously). I brought that up because you didn't show enough code for me to answer it.

Comment: 1) in the dataset I am actually working on, I am using a continuous variable with color using the "coolwarm" colormap. I have another variable that is categorical that might be valuable to have represented by shape
2) I think I actually copy pasted this example from another postand slightly modified the graph.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev4Q4.png

Trying to combine these 3 graphs into one, where the category gets represented by the shape. I have a 3 other groupings like this, So it would reduce about 15 graphs into 4.

Comment: @jdsdog10 You can vary the marker shapes by using the `style` and `markers` arguments of [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot).